# Vue.js $.ajax() dynamic table when document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, vue.js

I'm trying to find a solution with for a table that is populated with $.ajax(), but i can't figure out how i can do this with Vue.js. How can I do that? Do i need a Vue component for that?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 overflow-table">
        <table class="table" id="table">
        <thead class="head-color thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-left:1px solid transparent;">NAME</th>
                <th>CLIENT-ID</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-right:1px solid transparent;">ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id='table-redirect'>
            <tr class='lightgrey'>
            </tr>
            <tr class='lightgrey'>
            </tr>
            <tr class='lightgrey'>
            </tr>
            <tr class='lightgrey'>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**VUE.JS SCRIPT:**

```
    //VUE.JS REDIRECT PAGE

//VARIABLES
var url = "http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/redirect";
agr = 0;

//VUE.JS REDIRECT VIEW MODEL
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#redirect',
  delimiters:['{', '}'],

  data: {
    agr1:[]
  },

  methods: {

  //FUNCTION TO DISPLAY TABLE ON PAGE (RE)LOAD
      getAll: function() {
        console.log('teste');
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "/getAll",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(response){
              console.log(response);//
              this.agr1=response;
              console.log(this.agr1);
              console.log('success!');
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log('error');
            }//end error function
        });//end $.ajax() request
      },//end getAll function
  }//end methods
})//end vue.js instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<tr>` like a list. Add a `v-for="agr in agr1"` then you can iterate over the properties you want. when `agr1` gets updated it'll render a new list of rows. You can also use `v-bind:key="agr.property"` to make it so that Vue efficiently renders the elements that get reused.

```
    <tbody id='table-redirect'>
        <tr 
          v-for="agr in agr1"
          v-bind:key="agr.id"
          class='lightgrey'
        >
            <td>{{ agr.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ agr.client_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ agr.url }}</td>
            <td>{{ agr.actions }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Btw, the actions section has 2 buttons with <img>. I know how could I use it with jQuery, but to put a working button with vue.js? the buttons are also dynamic like the data. And when I click the edit button, it edits the content of the selected row.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard so long as each object has the dynamic data needed.
`<td><img src="action1.png" v-on:click="doFunction1(agr)"><img src="action2.png" v-on:click="doFunction2(agr)"></td>`

Comment: Ah! I understand now! :) another question, after some search, shouldn't the ajax function be inside `mounted()` instead of `methods: {}`?

Comment: Keep it in `methods` and call it in `mounted` that way if you want to have the ability to update the information you can just call the `getAll` function

Comment: `mounted: function() {
    getAll();
   },` ?

Comment: `mounted: function() { this.getAll(); },` Don't forget about your scoping. To access object members you have to use `this` to get the current instance scope.

Comment: It's working! :) Thank you so much for your help! @Justin MacArthur. You were a great help!

Comment: so sorry for bothering you again, everything is working, except the data is not appeding to the table :/ @Justin MacArthur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145056/discussion-between-justin-macarthur-and-timmy).